# execute method not calling in test class

Tags: unit-test

```
global class DeleteBatch implements Database.Batchable<sObject> {

    global String queryString;


    global operansDeleteBatch(){
               }

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {

        return Database.getQueryLocator(queryString);
    }

    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sobject> scope) {
        querylstScopeRecords = scope;
    }   

    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    }
}
```

this is my test class code

```
@isTest
 public class DeleteBatch_Test {

     public static testMethod void unitTest() {


     DeleteBatch obj =new DeleteBatch();

     Database.executeBatch(obj); 

     }
 }
```

Comment: Can you post your test code. I expect the most likely reason is that your test is not setting-up any data for the batch to run against.

Comment: @isTest
 public class operationsDeleteBatch_Test {
 
     public static testMethod void unitTest() {
     
     
     operationsDeleteBatch obj =new operationsDeleteBatch();
     
     Database.executeBatch(obj); 
     
  
     
     
     
     }
 }

Comment: @VipinIndora use Test.setCreatedDate() to set proper data before Database.executeBatch(obj); , so that your execute method gets non-empty result set to perform execute().

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You test does not set-up any data for the batch to execute against. To test this batch you would first need to insert some `DiscoverOrg_Operation__c` rows before running the batch.

Here is a brief example, but you'd probably want to insert more data and may also want to look at the `@testSetup` attribute/method too.

```
@isTest public class operationsDeleteBatch_Test { 

  public static testMethod void unitTest() { 

    DiscoverOrg_Operation__c data = new DiscoverOrg_Operation__c();
    // TODO: Set any fields required on your object.
    insert data;

    Test.setCreatedDate(data.Id, DateTime.now().addDays(-32));

    test.startTest();
    operationsDeleteBatch obj =new operationsDeleteBatch();
    Database.executeBatch(obj); 
    test.stopTest();

    // TODO: Add your assertions here.

  } 

}
```

Comment: insert data but nothing effects still coverage 62%

Comment: I've updated the answer. Your query has a filter for based on the created date so you need to use `test.setCreatedDate` so that it is included in your SOQL query.

Comment: DateTime.now.addDays(-32)) showing error DateTime. now is not valid.
 i think system.today().addDays(-32) will work

Comment: Typo. Missed the () after now. Although you should have easily spotted that :)

Comment: use  in my code but still coverage not increasing its still 62%

Comment: Are you setting isBatchesCompleted__c to true on data?

Comment: this is formula field i cant set true manualy

Comment: You would need to set the relevant fields on the line `// TODO: Set any fields required on your object.` that cause the formula field to evaluate to true - as specified in your SOQL query in the batch.